# Vuex mutation error when pass Object (with objects) to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

**Description(tl;dr):**

When I pass "Object of Objects" from vuex's store to components via `v-model`, the model's modifications produce error. **Only** when "Object of Objects" passed. With any other type everything is ok.

When i told "Object of Objects" i mean this structure: `{'A': {name: 'first'}, 'B': {name: 'second'}}`.

**Workflow and structire**:

- Structure: `view (page)` -> `parent` -> `child`;
- View get an `Object` from store and pass it down to components (->`parrent`->`child`);
- No "`.sync`" allowed, so components should't mutate object in store;
- After changes in `child`, `child` have to return result to `parent`, `parent` to `view`, and `view` should save it via vuex's setter;

**The Error message**:

```
Error when evaluating setter "value.name": Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers. (found in component: <child>)
```

**Getter (from store)**:

```
getObjFromStore // return {'A': {name: 'first'}, 'B': {name: 'second'}}
```

**View (page)**:

```
<parent :value="getObjFromStore"></parent>
```

**Parent component**:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="v in value">
    <child :value="v"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from 'components/child'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {}
    },
    props: {
      value: {
        type: Object
      }
    },
    components: {
      Child
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Child component**:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value.name">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {}
    },
    props: {
      value: {
        type: Object
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**P.S.** I assume that the problem happens because Objects passed by reference. But how to fight this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically only 2 options:

1. Pass a deepcopy of the object to `props`;
2. Use `@input` event or `v-model` with computed props (Like in pkawiak's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249362/930170);

I prefer to use deepcopy while I'm sure that object isn't too big. This approach helps to keep code more clean, and much more easier for maintenance.

Second approach only for cases when expected object is bloody-big

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Vuex form handling](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html) docs. It encourages using `@input` event or `v-model` with computed props...

> Assuming obj is a computed property that returns an Object from the store, the v-model here will attempt to directly mutate obj.message when the user types in the input. In strict mode, this will result in an error because the mutation is not performed inside an explicit Vuex mutation handler.

Comment: I already knew it, but `@input` not fit for my case and I can't define a custom getter/setter inside my component, cause I have to use events and use setter on top(view). I want to understand why this error occurs only when Object with Objects inside have passed

Comment: Well if you get an object from the store, it should only be modified via mutations, not by direct setters on an object (and those are utilized by `v-model`). I'm a bit confused... are you trying to mix and match Vuex and vanilla Vue approaches in one app?

Comment: Yeah, cause low-level component should't know anything about stores. Basically `userView` -> `userList` -> `list`. Than `List` should provide data (changed) directly to `userList`, but not to store. And `userList` can contain some other elements (buttons) and should provide data directly to `userView`. View have own store and save own state into it. Does my workflow sucks?

Comment: The idea behind it is to allow `userList` to work with any other page (each page have own store). And `list` can be also a general part of a `userList`, `carList` and etc.

Comment: So and the problem is that lower component (`list`), should pass one-way binded data. But the data is two-way binded somewhy

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, you can pass a **deep copy** of an object returned from the store to underlying components. Those components then modify that object as they please using `v-model`. At some point in time `list` dispaches an event with changed data (e.g. on some button click) and `userView`watches for this event and dispatches proper mutations... that could work but I seriously wouldn't do it

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot